# Create Default Back Button with Custom Button in LeftBarButtonItems ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating a project where I need to have a **default back button** and **custom filter button** on the left side of the navigation bar.

I have created custom back button, custom filter button and add both of them to leftBarButtonItems

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = alignedLeftBarButtonItems()

    func alignedLeftBarButtonItems() -> [UIBarButtonItem] {

            let filterButton = createLeftCustomBarButton()

            // back button creation
            let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: R.image.navBackArrow(), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.backButtonPressed(_:)))
            backButton.tintColor = UIColor.white

            let barButtonsItems = [
                backButton,
                UIBarButtonItem(customView: filterButton)
            ]
            return barButtonsItems
        }
```

Things are fine and working.

**Concern:**

> Default, User can go to the previous **VC** by sliding from left to
>   right. This functionality is lost in making this. Is there a way I can
>   have both buttons with the sliding functionality.

[image: Nav Bar]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UIBarButtonItem` to use default left or right swipe functionality for back button:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: Image.backButton, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(actionBackButton))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

> With Custom button, you cannot get this functionality

Comment: I need to have two bar buttons in the navigation bar.

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta: you need both button in left side?

Comment: yes both on the left side. I will upload a view as per my requirement

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta: You need to add left button as i have suggested and if you want to add another button then use title view or rightview

Comment: That's what, I have to have it on the left side of the nav bar, not on title view or right view. Thanks

Comment: You can add button in left side in title view

Comment: Otherwise you don't have any option to get default functionality